# Can someone tell me how to create a QR code for a url with parameters

Tags: url, qr-code, encode, parameters

I've tried using a few web pages to create QR code to create a QR for a regular url and they fine.

However, if I had parameters to the url, the resulting url does not decode properly.

If you try this

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=500x500&choe=UTF-8&chld=H&chl=http://localhost?someparam=1&someotherparam=2
```

instead of the QR code pointing to  `http://localhost?someparam=1&someotherparam=2`

the Barcodescanner decoder apps on Android and iPhone point to

```
http://localhost/?someparam=1&someotherparam=2
```

The forward slash /  between what would be the server name (domain name) and the start of the parameter string is obviously incorrect.

I'm assuming that it's something to do with url encoding and I'm just looking for a pointer in the right direction from someone who might had already cracked this nut.

Zxing's QR code generator has the same effect. But it seems to rely on Google also.

http://zxing.appspot.com/generator/

Also

http://d-project.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/misc/qrcode/js/sample.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [URL-encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) each parameter value, in your example, the `chl` parameter in particular. Most languages have libraries for this these days or a web search for "url encoder " will give you a form.

The url encoding of `http://localhost?someparam=1&someotherparam=2` is `http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3Fsomeparam%3D1%26someotherparam%3D2`.

Also, any parameter values to a URL that is itself a parameter value have to be independently URL encoded as well.

As Sean mentions below, if you enter your URL into the form on the appspot page, it correctly URL encodes the chart url:

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=350x350&chld=L&choe=UTF-8&chl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3Fsomeparam%3D1%26someotherparam%3D
```

I'm not sure about your extra `/` comment. If you go to the URL you give, the code value is

```
http://localhost?someparam=1
```

which is what is expected because the `chl` parameter value is not escaped and therefore ends at the first `&`.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. If I paste that into the zxing QR code generator, it gives an invalid URL error. If I just take the parameters and leave the rest of the url unencoded, then I get a QR code, but the params aren't part of the url when scanned.

Comment: @user1325094, no, the generator is simply doing for you exactly what smparkes describes, which is correct. You can't paste your already-escaped URL in. Paste your original URL in, and it will do the right thing.

Comment: I must have been having some sort of brain melt, but now this is working. However I've seen other people on the web asking the same question, so perhaps I wasn't smoking dope.